# ¿Un literal de texto puede participar en expresión constante sólo si es usado directamente?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Supongamos que tenemos una función `constexpr` que hace una operación sobre un literal de texto:

```
template <typename char_t, unsigned size>
constexpr auto f(const char_t (&s)[size])
{
    std::size_t result{};
    for (const auto &c : s)
        result += c;
    return result;
}
```

Puede usarse en contextos `constexpr` con normalidad:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    switch (i)
    {
        case f("Hola mundo!"):
            std::cout << "Eureka!\n";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Sapristi!\n";
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Pero si tenemos una función `constexpr` que recibe los mismos parámetros y delega en la primera función, el parámetro deja de ser una expresión constante:

```
template <typename char_t, unsigned size>
constexpr auto f2(const char_t (&s)[size])
{
    constexpr auto x = f(s);
    return x + 2;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = f2("Hola mundo!");
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

[El código anterior](https://tio.run/##pZDNasMwEITP1lNMUwg2acH10XFy7juUUoS8SQXWD9IK3IY8uyu7hkChvfS4s98Ms6u8fzwrNU332qoh9YROu8iBpDkKwWT8IDmL/OHJSkNQ7zK88QOSjfpsqUfUn3QUytnINPoAmdjhVC7CSqPcxuplBl8rcRFF5L5t5zGvAsU08OW6F8XJBay@JWSr0CJWoii@IewOUJkLxCnY1bkX1//0bP4s@oMecciXxerWYcQOzVJBW4aR2pa/Gpty8@wGCZNs7@42c8ryCOUSo@sw3mLrHDlNT3Vdiy8) muestra los siguientes errores:

> ```
> In instantiation of ‘constexpr auto f2(const char_t (&)[size]) [with char_t = char; unsigned int size = 12]’:
>    required from here
>    in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘f<char, 12>((* & s))’
>  error: the value of ‘s’ is not usable in a constant expression
>   constexpr auto x = f(s);
>                  ^
>  ‘s’ was not initialized with a constant expression
>  constexpr auto f2(const char_t (&s)[size])
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
>  In function ‘int main()’:
>  error: ‘constexpr const void x’ has incomplete type
>   constexpr auto x = f2("Hola mundo!");
>                  ^
> ```

El parámetro `s` puede ser considerado `constexpr` cuando es llamado con un literal de texto cuando se pasa a `f`, pero si llamamos `f2` con un literal de texto para dentro pasarlo a una variable `constexpr` calculada con `f`, no se considera `constexpr`. ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Answer (score 0):

## Lamentablemente solo puede usarse directamente

No es posible pasar un `consxpr` como `const` y luego usarlo o convertirlo nuevamente en `constexpr`.

Esto compila:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto f(const auto a)
{
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    constexpr auto b = f(3);
    std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Pero al agregar el `std::cout` ya no compila:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto f(const auto a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    constexpr auto b = f(3);
    std::cout<<b<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Algunos detalles en tu ejemplo:

- En el primer `main`, `i` como `int` pero se le está pasando un *string* `Hola mundo!`.
- En el segundo `main`, se puede resolver quitando `constexpr` y dejando solamente `auto` o `const auto`.

Llamando a `f`:

```
auto x = f(s);
```

Llamando a `f2`:

```
auto x = f2("Hola mundo!");
```

Otra solución es cambiando `constexpr auto x` por `const auto x`:

```
const auto x = f2("Hola mundo!");
```

Declarando como `std::size_t`:

```
const std::size_t x = f(s);
```

Código final:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename char_t, unsigned size>
constexpr auto f(const char_t (&s)[size])
{
    std::size_t result{};
    for (const auto &c : s){
        result += c;
        std::cout << (std::size_t)(c) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << result << std::endl;
    return result;
}
template <typename char_t, unsigned size>
constexpr auto f2(const char_t (&s)[size])
{
    auto x = f(s);
    return x + 2;
}
int main()
{
    auto x = f2("Hola mundo!");
    std::cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```